# R CMD check doesn't detect my documentation

Tags: r

When I run

```
R CMD build mypackage
R CMD check mypackage_1.0.tar.gz
```

I'm getting this warning:

```
Undocumented code objects:
  ‘func1’ ‘func2’
```

However, my package structure has these functions documented in the `man` folder:

```
$ ls mypackage
DESCRIPTION  man  NAMESPACE  R  README.md  tests
```

And these functions specifically have documentation:

```
$ ll mypackage/man
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  307 May 24 14:38 func1.Rd
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  307 May 29 15:38 func2.Rd
```

Which looks like so:

```
$ cat mypackage/man/func1.R
\name{ func1 }
\title{ Do func1}
\description{
  This is well documented
  }
```

What am I missing to tell R this is where my documentation is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add an alias.

```
$ cat mypackage/man/func1.R
\name{ func1 }
\alias{ func1 }
\title{ Do func1}
\description{
  This is well documented
  }
```

This should do it.

Comment: Did you mean "I"? It seems you asked the question.